SQL Server Windows Authentication not working within server: "The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication"
I have SQL Server 2017 installed as the default instance hosted on a virtual server (GoDaddy) running Windows Server 2019 (this is a live production server). SQL is configured for mixed-mode authentication, which works perfectly in all respects when I log in using SQL Server Authentication. Because it's a default instance, the name of the SQL instance is the same as the Server Name ("MyServerName" -- not actual name, but using it for this post). When I connect to the Database Engine via SSMS, selecting MyServerName as the server and SQL Server Authentication with a SQL account (sysadmin), I can create a new Login using Windows authentication for user: MyServerName\adminusername. That Login shows up (as expected) under Security/Logins as "MyServerName\adminusername". I can assign this new Windows authentication user to the Server Role sysadmin, and also establish that new user as db Owner for any database (as long as I'm logged in to SQL Server using SQL Authentication). All of this is competely normal behavior.
But here's where it gets weird: If I then log in to Windows on this same server (MyServerName) using that same "adminusername" user (who is a Windows Administrator on the server), then try to connect to the same instance of SQL server (MyServerName) via SSMS using Windows Authentication mode and the same user (MyServerName\adminusername), I get the following error:

The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with
Integrated authentication. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18452)

Just to reiterate:

This problem is all within a single Windows server and a single instance of SQL Server (not trying to connect between two different servers).
The name of the Windows Server is MyServerName.
The server is not configured as a Domain Controller (it never has been).
The name of the SQL Server instance (default instance) is MyServerName.
I have no trouble when logging in to SQL server with SQL authentication.
I have no trouble logging into Windows Server as MyServerName\adminusername.
Even though I can create a Windows Authentication login as "MyServerName\adminusername", and "MyServerName" is both the Windows server name and the name of the SQL Server instance (default), it seems to think there is a mismatch between the "domain" (MyServerName) for the Windows authentication Login and the instance of SQL Server itself.

I've been developing databases and associated web applications in SQL Server for over 15 years and have never seen this issue before. I've been all over the internet trying to find someone describing a similar issue, but so far no luck (other answers involve connections between multiple servers or SQL instances, or other very specific circumstances that do not apply to my situation).
The only thing I can think of is that, when the virtual server was first created, GoDaddy set the server name as the IP address (replacing '.' with '-'). I changed the name of the server to its current name, but it's possible that I installed SQL Server when the Server name was still the original one assigned by GoDaddy, and then changed the server name after SQL installation.
Even though the server has never been a Domain Controller, I've seen indications that SQL Server will need to be re-installed when switching to a Domain Controller. I wonder if the same is true if the Computer Name has been changed, even if is not a Domain Controller?  To test this, I've tried reverting the computer name back to what the original computer name assigned by GoDaddy, but I continued to have the exact same issue.
I'm tempted to try to uninstall SQL Server and re-install it again, but that would be days of work to re-configure all the different databases and associated websites/etc. I'm willing to do that if the probability of success is high, but at this stage I'm not confident enough that it will solve the issue in order to justify that amount of work and offline time of various websites.
Incidentally, the reason I need to be able to fix this Windows Authentication login issue is that I need to set up replication (which uses Windows Login process accounts for various Agents). So "just use SQL authentication" isn't a viable work-around solution.
EDIT: I forgot to mention, whenever I attempt to log in to SQL server using Windows Authentication, the Server Manager records an Application log event for MSSQLSERVER that says:

SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x8009030c, state 14 while
establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has
been closed. Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failed. The operating
system error code indicates the cause of failure. The logon attempt
failed.

I doubt that provides anything not already evident from the full description above, but adding it for completeness.

Is that account in the list of users who can "Access this computer from the network" (in secpol.msc -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignments)

Most likely an SPN issue. Check the SPNs.

@SeanGallardy Missing SPN usually gets "The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context"

@Charlieface true, though I've seen it (depending on setups) have this error. I didn't see the edit to the question but the error is 0x8009030c which is SEC_E_LOGON_DENIED so definitely an issue with account/permissions in Windows/AD.

@Charlieface:  Thanks, and yes the account explicitly has access to the computer from the network (also is a member of Administrators group).

@SeanGallardy: I did consider SPN, but I confess I have very little experience  with Kerberos authentication. I've never encountered this issue before , but I suppose that, since this instance of Windows Server was pre-installed by GoDaddy, they might have done something different that requires me to configure AD in a way I've never needed to do before. I'm also perplexed by why that might be an issue when it's a Windows user directly logged into the same machine (i.e., no attempt to connect from a different server or workstation).

I'm not sure about the issue, but you could create another non-default sql server just to see if you can get windows auth working on it perhaps. If you have a problem there, then something is terribly wrong (i'm guessing SPN too). Is there a domain somewhere? Or is the server just a local one (workgroup)?

Thanks, @siggemannen!  Yeah, I might try that (create a separate named instance of SQL to see if that works).  I'd still need to re-install the default instance to make everything work, but at least this test could give me confidence that doing so might solve the underlying issue. The server is NOT configured with a Domain Controller (only the local WORKGROUP).

Btw, how did you add the windows user to sql server? did you go to SSMS dialog and clicked on "Search..." and browsed to the correct user name on the User-dialog? Or did you enter the name directly. Maybe it will help doing it the hard way and going through the GUI

Either way, this is not using Kerberos if it's not joined to the domain, it's using NTLM. But it should have worked. Have you tried logging off/on or even a full reboot? I agree might be worth removing the SQL login and user, and readding it.

@siggemannen: Yes, I clicked "Search" in the New Login dialog (with Windows authentication selected), entered "adminusername" and clicked "Checked names" button, and the username was converted to "MyServerName\adminusername" (underscored) automatically. In other words, it selected the actual Windows login for MyServerName\adminusername.

@Charlieface: Yes, that's why I was thinking it wasn't a Domain/Kerberos issue (but wasn't sure). Yes, I've logged on/off Windows with multiple different admin-level Windows accounts (even created some test ones as new users in Windows, just to check).  I've restarted Windows several times. I can request GoDaddy to do a full reboot of the virtual server if that might help. Also removed/added several Win-Auth users from SQL several times, and tried a half-dozen other Win logins (including some tests). All Win-Auth users have exactly the same problem.

Just as an update: I had GoDaddy do a proper reboot of the server (not just restarting Windows), and it did not solve the issue.  I didn't expected to, but figured it was worth a shot.
